# JavaScript FETCH: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I'm getting this whenever I send a POST request to the URL API I'm using. Here's the error I always got is,

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()
```

Here is the code I used:

```
var firstName = "John";
var lastName = "Doe"
var company = "Doeroe Consulting Group, Asia"
var profileURL = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/johndoe/"
var email = "kg111@gmail.com"
var phone = "09161111524"
var website = "";
var jd = "";

//send the data to the api script
send_data(firstName, lastName, company, profileURL, email, phone, website, company, jd); 


function send_data(firstName, lastName, company, profileURL, email, phone, website, company, jd){

//api call to outplayhq
var url = 'https://us3-api.outplayhq.com/api/v1/prospect?client_id=CLIENT_ID';
var secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
var data = {
    "emailid": email,
    "firstname": firstName,
    "lastname": lastName,
    "phone": phone,
    "designation": jd,
    "timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
    "city": "",
    "linkedin": profileURL,
    "state": "",
    "country": "",
    "twitter": "",
    "facebook": "",
    "company": company,
    }

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'X-CLIENT-SECRET': 'CLIENT_SECRET',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

Hopefully you can help figure out what I'm missing on the fetch setup. Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't use `mode: 'no-cors'`

Comment: Hi @Unmitigated, I tried but I got this error:

Access to fetch at 'https://us3-api.outplayhq.com/api/v1/prospect?client_id=Z6P3w3TGPNbR8Jb9EwaZVg==' from origin 'https://www.linkedin.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: You could add `https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/` in front of your URL to avoid the CORS issue.

Comment: But are you sure this is the correct way to use this API? Is there some way for you to configure the CORS allowed origins?

Comment: Are you sure the API at us3-api.outplayhq.com accepts JSON?